# Linker error __sincosf_stret

Tags: c++, c, macos, clang

I am getting linker error on Mac OS X as following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___sincosf_stret", referenced from:
```

Following functions are being used inside the function where it shows the error in my program:

```
cosf
sinf
```

libm is being linked using -lm.
I am using Xcode 5 preview and OS is Mac OS X Mavericks Developer Preview.

I am unable to find the reason behind this linker error.

When I linked using Mac OS X 10.9 SDK and minimum target is 10.9, then it is working fine. But setting of my development environment is to use Mac OS X 10.8 SDK (as other developers have 10.8 SDK) and minimum target is 10.6.

Is there any way to get around this problem for target 10.6 using SDK 10.8?

Comment: AFAIK  10.9 is still under NDA.  Please report a bug or post your question on devforms.apple.com.  That said, did you clean all targets after changing the SDK and min version?

Comment: What is this function?  Which framework/library does it come from?

Comment: @trojanfoe: It seems to come from math.h. I am not using this function.

Comment: @StephenCanon: Yes. I cleaned all targets after changing SDK and min version.

Comment: The thing is I don't recognise it and get no hits when googling.  Please provide more information about where it comes from, else I fear no-one can help you at all.

Comment: @StephenCanon: “devforms.apple.com” → “devforums.apple.com”.

Comment: @trojanfoe: __sincosf_stret comes from Stephen Canon, who responded above.

Comment: @StephenCanon: It seems to be a problem in SDK as there is no such error on Mountain Lion using Xcode 4.6.

Comment: @dbasic: thanks for posting on the devforums. I’ll follow up with you there.